# Using wildcard to create a 301 redirect

Tags: dns, wildcard, forwarding

I have a domain which all the urls are structured like this:

```
http://www.documents-myapp.com/how-to-use
http://www.documents-myapp.com/basic-instructions
http://www.documents-myapp.com/configuration-setuo
http://www.documents-myapp.com/and many other urls
```

I want to setup a redirect so every individual page goes to a different domain:

```
https://myurl-myapp.com/documents/how-to-use
https://myurl-myapp.com/documents/basic-instructions
https://myurl-myapp.com/documents/configuration-setuo
https://myurl-myapp.com/documents/and many other urls
```

so the domain `http://www.documents-myapp.com/` is changed to `https://myurl-myapp.com/documents/` and the urls after remain the same.

Any ideas how to setup this redirect using wildcard?